# Graphing $x^3$ polynomial functions. How to change the middle part of the function but keep the end behaviors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm working on polynomials.  The equation for the graph below is $$f(x) = x^2(x-2)$$  The x intercepts are (0,0) and (2,0).  In the graph that is attached the functions touches the x axis at (0,0), it goes down(1, -1), back up, and then passes straight through the x axis at (2,0).

I was wondering, how could I have the function pass through (0,0) go to (1,1) and not (1, -1). Then have the graph come back down touch (2,0) and then go back up?  I'd like to keep the end behaviors and just change the middle.

[image]

Comment: So (0,0), (1,1), (2,0) is three equations; there's a one-parameter family of cubics that go through those three points. One way to describe that family is $x(x-2)(ax-b)$ where $(1)(-1)(a-b)=1$ so that $b=a+1$. A less "manual" way to do that calculation is Newton interpolation.

Comment: I was taught a small amount of interpolation and extrapolation in a linear unit when we were plotting points and drawing the line of best fit.  I am afraid when I looked at Newton interpolation, the notation was dauting.  How would I begin to understand that?  Looking forward to entering a calculous 1 class at sometime.  Would I learn it then? thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have much in the way of prerequisites really, it's mostly self-contained, but typically you wouldn't see it until after the entire calculus sequence in a numerical analysis class. For your level and a question like this I'd just keep it simple, since two of the interpolation points are zeros and so it is easy enough to just do a hackjob manual calculation to deal with the third one. If they were three general points then this would be a pretty tedious linear system calculation if you did it by brute force.

Comment: I'll just keep hacking!  The section on multiplicity which I am looking at now is also helpful as to how a factor with the multiplicity of 1 passes through the x axes and how a factor with the multiplicity of 2 bounces off.  I think this will help also in estimating how a polynomial function will act near the x axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cubics going through $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ are of the form $x(x-2)(ax-b)$. Those that pass through $(1,1)$ will have $b=a+1$ so the form becomes $x(x-2)(ax-a-1)$. It sounds like you don't want a root greater than $2$ so you want $0 \leq \frac{a+1}{a} \leq 2$ so $-1 \leq \frac{1}{a} \leq 1$ so $|a| \geq 1$. To maintain the end behavior you need $a>0$, so that becomes $a \geq 1$.

For instance $a=1$ gives $x(x-2)^2$ which seems to fit your description, but for instance $x(x-2)(2x-3)$ would work too.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ian's comment you can treat this as a system of equations, with the points (0,0), (1,1) and (2,0) giving you three equations by plugging them in to the formula for a general cubic:  $y = Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$

(0,0) gives:

$0 = 0+0+0+D$ , so $D=0$

(1,1) gives:

$1=A+B+C+D$

(2,0) gives:

$0 = 8A + 4B+2C+D$

So, you have three equations involving the 4 unknown coefficients of the cubic.  You can now solve the system, perhaps using Gauss-Jordan elimination.  Since you have less equations then unknowns there will be a "free variable" which means that actually there are infinitely many cubics that go through those 3 points.  If you want to keep the same end behavior then that is really determined by whether A is positive or negative.  So, one solution would be to go ahead and just pick A=1 or any other positive constant and then solve for the missing B/C values.